Amorphic modules are totally disconnected
Let $A$ be an abelian locally compact (LC) Hausdorff group. An LC $A$-module is said to be sheer if it has no nontrivial parafinite compact submodule and the only open submodule such that the quotient admits finite nontrivial submodules is the module itself. Moreover, we say that an LC $A$-module is amorphic if it is both sheer and compact-by-discrete.
It can be proved that an amorphic module is always totally disconnected but I can't figure it out why.
I think a possible path is to show that the intersection of all open submodules is 0, in this case I was able to prove the totally disconnectedness. Moreover, it can be proved also the "dual" statement (dual in the sense of Pontryagin duality) that is that the sum of all compact submodules is the full module and that this implies that the module is the union of its compact submodules, but I am not able to "dualize" the proof.
Thanks to anyone who will help.

Let $M$ be amorphic, and let us show that $M$ is totally disconnected. Let $U$ be an open compact submodule (which exists by assumption). Let $M^\circ$ be the connected component of $0$. Then $M\subseteq U$, and hence $M^\circ$ is compact. Being also connected, it follows that $M^\circ$ is compact parafinite, and by the definition of $M$ being sheer, it follows that $M^\circ=\{0\}$.
